# java.lang.IllegalAccessError :MappingCassandraConverter Error when doing insert using Spring Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise, datastax-java-driver, spring-data-cassandra

I am new to Spring so please pardon my rudimentary question. I am using spring-based cassandra to do some CRUD operations. A simple insert does not seem to be working and was wondering if someone can point out what I am doing wrong. Below is the error I get when I simply do an insert

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BeanWrapper from class org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.writeInsertFromObject(MappingCassandraConverter.java:233) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.convert.MappingCassandraConverter.write(MappingCassandraConverter.java:222) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.createInsertQuery(CassandraTemplate.java:841) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.doInsert(CassandraTemplate.java:640) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:238) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.CassandraTemplate.insert(CassandraTemplate.java:233) ~[spring-data-cassandra-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
```

Here is code:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:cassandra.properties" })
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public CassandraOperations cassandraTemplate(Session someSession) throws Exception {
         return new CassandraTemplate(someSession);
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraMappingContext mappingContext() {
        return new BasicCassandraMappingContext();
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConverter converter() {
        return new MappingCassandraConverter(mappingContext());
    }}
```

Assuming the session is valid. Here is the code to actually do the writes

```
@Component
public class SomeQueries {
@Autowired
CassandraOperations cassandraOps;

public void insertCart(Addresses addr){
    cassandraOps.insert(addr);
}
}
```

Here is the Object for Address:

```
    @Data
        @NoArgsConstructor
        @Table(value = "addresses")
        public class Addresses implements Serializable{

            @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "account_id", ordinal = 0, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
            private UUID accountId;

            @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "address_id", ordinal = 1, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
            private int addressId;

            @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "is_primary", ordinal = 2, type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
            private boolean isPrimary;

            @Column("name") private String name;
            @Column("creation_date") private Date creationTimestamp;
            @Column("last_modified_date") private Date lastModifiedTimestamp;   

            @Override
            public int hashCode() {
                final int prime = 31;
                int result = 1;
                result = prime * result + ((accountId == null) ? 0 : accountId.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + addressId;
                result = prime * result + ((creationTimestamp == null) ? 0 : creationTimestamp.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + (isPrimary ? 1231 : 1237);
                result = prime * result + ((lastModifiedTimestamp == null) ? 0 : lastModifiedTimestamp.hashCode());
                result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean equals(Object obj) {
                if (this == obj)
                    return true;
                if (obj == null)
                    return false;
                if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                    return false;
                DeliveryAddresses other = (DeliveryAddresses) obj;
                if (accountId == null) {
                    if (other.accountId != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!accountId.equals(other.accountId))
                    return false;
else if (!address.equals(other.address))
                    return false;
                if (addressId != other.addressId)
                    return false;
                if (creationTimestamp == null) {
                    if (other.creationTimestamp != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!creationTimestamp.equals(other.creationTimestamp))
                    return false;
                if (isPrimary != other.isPrimary)
                    return false;
                if (lastModifiedTimestamp == null) {
                    if (other.lastModifiedTimestamp != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!lastModifiedTimestamp.equals(other.lastModifiedTimestamp))
                    return false;
                if (name == null) {
                    if (other.name != null)
                        return false;
                } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
                    return false;
                return true;
            }
            }
```

Is there something that I am missing to initialize?

Comment: Can you add versions of Spring, and Spring Data Cassandra you are using? I see in latest code of Spring Data Cassandra that they removed BeanWrapper from MappingCassandraConverter (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/convert/MappingCassandraConverter.java) so you might upgrade to latest version (1.3.0) if it is option for you?

Comment: Thanks...I updated the version and that seems to be resolving the issues.

Comment: No problem, I added answer to your question for future references. You can mark it as accepted if it solved your problem and maybe add version of Spring Data CAssandra which you used so people who stumble on same problem can relate to version

Answer (score 0):

BeanWrapper is deprecated in Spring Data Cassandra 1.2.0. version and marked for removal with TODO note in code and in latest code on Github for [MappingCassandraConverter](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/master/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/convert/MappingCassandraConverter.java) BeanWrapper it has been removed.

You can upgrade Spring Data Cassandra to version 1.3.0 and BeanWrapper exception will go away.